# Lightning Network wallet applications for different operating systems?

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, e-wallet

What are the best / most secure wallet applications of Lightning Network for each of following operating systems/platforms ?

- Windows
- Mac OS
- android
- iOS
- web browser extensions

Answer (score 4):

Android Lightning Network wallets

https://github.com/ACINQ/eclair-mobile

https://lightning-wallet.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It'll be nice if you could also mention reliable LN wallets for other platforms such as iOS, Windows etc to complete your answer. Thanks